SSIS Task Factory insert/upsert not working. Instead it returns to invalid Input option
I have a staging table which has current day record and a historical table. So my staging table has 100 new records with SCD 2 change in records. I have configured Task factory with business key,surrogatekey and all other columns as SCD2.
In row detection tab earlier when I had not selected the nullable option for SCD2 columns, I had faced same error " Invalid input". It worked 2 days before.  Now cross checked everything and it  says Invalid input again (double the input qty. eg historical has 1000 records and error says 2000 invalid input) and 0 new records and 0 scd 2 records. I still have nullable option enabled for all SCD 2 columns. Could you please help with some insights on how to fix this.
